# I cannot get the plot to show when using the kaplan meier package in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make kaplan meier curves for some research. I am using this package:
https://github.com/erdogant/kaplanmeier

When I run the example code that is provided in the documentation I am able to get the plots to actually show up. Here is the code they provide:

```
# Import library
import kaplanmeier as km
# Example data
df = km.example_data()

time_event = df['time']
censoring = df['Died']
y = df['group']

results = km.fit(df['time'], df['Died'], df['group'])
# Plot
km.plot(results)

km.plot(results, cmap='Set1', cii_lines=True, cii_alpha=0.05)
km.plot(results, cmap=[(1, 0, 0),(0, 0, 1)])
km.plot(results, cmap='Set1', methodtype='custom')
```

When this runs, it shows 4 plots, 1 for each km.plot line.
However, if I comment out the very last line, none of them show up. In my own code I have this same issue.

```
import pandas as pd
import kaplanmeier as km
df = pd.read_csv("*********mydatafile******")
#the following line of code is just to reformat the data into a more reusable format
df.rename(columns ={'Did patient have surgery at any time after diagnosis specifically for atypical mycobacterial infection?':'surgery'}, inplace = True)
#the following line of code turns yes/no into 1 and 2
df['surgery'].replace({'No': 1, 'Yes': 2}, inplace = True)
time_event = df['Time to event']
censoring = df['Resolved']
y = df['surgery']
results = km.fit(time_event, censoring, y)
km.plot(results)
```

If I run the above, it doesn't show a plot. But if I add that very last line from the example code to the bottom of my code it then shows 2 plots, one of which is my km.plot(results). It seems that the methodtype = 'custom' is the specific part that makes it work.

I tried to look at the source code to figure it out, when you pass the methodtype = 'custom' parameter it seems that it calls _plotkm where as if you don't have methodtype = 'custom' I don't think it calls _plotkm. I'm a self taught beginner and just not facile enough in Python to actually figure out why this is happening.

I appreciate your help in advance!

I have explained everything above in depth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This package is based on [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/).

So a straight forward way to make the plots appear is to `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and use its [`show`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html) method to make them show up:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# [...your km code...]
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks!! Frustrating it doesn't work as advertised but this indeed solved the problem.